# Filter only X amounts of table's values (jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to combine filtering and displaying only 20 values per page of filtered table. Now the displaying itself and filtering is working, but can't combine them together.

The problem is after searching for specific values, it displays all the filtered values and then gets back to showing ALL values, instead of 20.

I can't seem to find a way to count how many values there are after filtering, then could force the same pagination for them.

Any tips?

```
//Display pagination & only x amount of values
$("#my-table").after('<tfoot> <tr> <td colspan="3" id="my-table-footer"></td> </tr> </tfoot>');
const showingRows = 20;
const rowsTotal = $("#my-table tr").length;
const numberOfPages = rowsTotal/showingRows;

for (i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
  let pageNumber = i + 1;
  $("#my-table-footer").append('<a href="#" rel="'+i+'">'+pageNumber+'</a> ');
}

$("#my-table tr").hide();
$("#my-table tr").slice(0, showingRows).show();


//Filter table
$("#mytable-filter-input").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $("#my-table tr").filter(function() {
  $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the browsers console for any errors? Cause I think you should first define I in the for loop like this `for (let i = 0, etc...)`

Comment: @spadletskys, the code is working fine above there. I am just looking for insights how I could know how many of values have actually been toggled with filter.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to get only 20 returns from 
`$(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)`